# Upgrade Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04 stuck on ''installing the firefox snap''

Tags: upgrade

I'm running the upgrade using the Software Updater, but now it's stuck here. [(see picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mp2U7.png)
The last line reads "=>Installing the firefox snap". It has been about one hour.

I do not have Firefox running, or any process related to it.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, after about 2 hours it started the installation again.

FYI, in case you'll run into the same issue.